# Windows Service not opening application GUI

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services

I'm trying to open an application(with it's GUI) thorough the windows service. It's not throwing any exception or error. Its not opening the application.
When I executed the same code with windows Forms app the applicaiton is opening.
Why the windows service is not opening any other application ?
My code is like below :

```
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                bool isinstalled = checkInstalled("AnyDesk");
                if (isinstalled)
                {
                    Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }
        }



        public static bool checkInstalled(string c_name)
        {
            string displayName;

            string registryKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
            RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registryKey);
            if (key != null)
            {
                foreach (RegistryKey subkey in key.GetSubKeyNames().Select(keyName => key.OpenSubKey(keyName)))
                {
                    displayName = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
                    if (displayName != null && displayName.Contains(c_name))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                key.Close();
            }

            registryKey = @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
            key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registryKey);
            if (key != null)
            {
                foreach (RegistryKey subkey in key.GetSubKeyNames().Select(keyName => key.OpenSubKey(keyName)))
                {
                    displayName = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
                    if (displayName != null && displayName.Contains(c_name))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                key.Close();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows Service applications run in a different "window station" than the logged-on user. Your application is opening and displaying on a hidden desktop that nobody can see.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/introduction-to-windows-service-applications

Comment: So, With windows service can't we open an app ? If so, Is there any alternate ?

Comment: What do you mean by hidden desktop ? Do you mean like while it was in sleep mode or shutdown mode ?

Comment: https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#GUIServices

Comment: @CoreTech There is no answer for my question in the URL which you send. My problem is to open another application(any desk) GUI. Not windows service GUI(ofcourse there wont be).

Comment: As @Brent suggests, Windows Services run in Session 0 -- a background session that no user can log in to. When your service starts the application, it is started in Session 0 and so is not visible on any user's desktop. You can confirm that your application is being started by looking in Task Manager (on the Details tab). Add the "Session ID" column to see where things are running.